# How to increment vector in r by a fixed value and generate histogram of each iteration

Tags: r, vector, iteration

I'm looking to iterate each value in the vector by 1 until a set value is reached and saving each iteration in a vector, and further iterations do not include values past the set value. So for instance say the set value is 3. Consider this vector, A <- c(1,1,2). Then the desired outcome should be:

```
Outcome:
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3
```

Then I want to store each line in a vector so I can plot a histogram
so with each vector outcome including the original vector.

```
hist(c(1,1,2))
hist(c(2,2,3))
hist(c(3,3))

Potential code:
for (i in 1:length(A)) {
      A[i] <- A + 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# given values
A <- c(1, 1, 2)
value <- 3 

# incrementations
out_lst <- lapply(A, function(x) x : 3)

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2 3

# histograms
hist_lst <- list()
max_len <- max(sapply(out_lst, function(x) length(x)))
for(l in 1:max_len) {
  hist_lst[[l]] <- sapply(out_lst, function(x) x[l])
}

hist_lst
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 2 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  3  3 NA

par(mfrow = c(1, length(hist_lst)))
invisible(lapply(hist_lst, hist))
```

Comment: You are reading the values columnwise while it should technically be rowwise. Re read the question.please look at the numbers he is using for the histogram

Comment: Well spotted. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
funfun=function(vec,max){
  y=list()
  i=1
  while(length(vec)!=0){
    y[[i]]=vec
    vec=vec+1
    vec=`attributes<-`(na.omit(replace(vec,vec>max,NA)),NULL)
    i=i+1
  }
  y
}

funfun(c(1,1,2),3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 3 3
```

you can now do

```
sapply(funfun(c(1,1,2),3),hist)
```